# Get the Dereferenced Keys From a Map

Tags: rust, iterator, btreemap

I'm trying to get the keys of a `BTreeMap` with `u32` keys.

When I use the `.iter().keys()` method, it returns a reference to the keys: `&u32`.

I understand the logic behind getting a reference to the key because it doesn't consume the data structure, but since `u32` implements the `Copy` trait, I figured it is possible to get `u32` directly.

The only way I found of doing this is by mapping over all the keys and dereferencing them:

```rust
let map = BTreeMap::from([
  (0, "foo"),
  (1, "bar"),
  (2, "baz")
])

let keys: Vec<u32> = map.iter().map(|(k, _)| *k).collect();
```

Is there a better, faster or more concise way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest either

```rust
let keys = map.keys().copied().collect();
```

or if you don't need the map any more:

```rust
let keys = map.into_keys().collect();
```

Comment: Thank you! Does the first option take longer since it iterates over the iterator twice? Is there some iterator magic going on that won't make it iterate twice?

Comment: Iterators are lazy meaning you only iterate once you repeatedly call `next` (possibly in a for-loop) or `collect` them or some other method that actually iterates so there is no multiple iterations in the first variant, only the final `collect`. That being said the first option has to copy all elements and thus is probably slightly slower, though i doub't you'll notice it in the real world.

Comment: @cafce25 Not necessarily; in the machine code, computing a reference or the actual value are usually both around the same time (if the value is in cache).